# My Libgdx game slow when integrated Admob

Tags: libgdx, admob

I am a new game developing with libgdx. I have a problem with Admob ads. When I call "adView.loadAd(adRequest);" my game is slowl, when I start game, FPS ~ 60 , when I call adView.loadAd(adRequest) my game is slowly FPS ~ 30.

Here is my

```
public class MainActivity extends AndroidApplication implements IActivityRequestHandler {

   protected AdView adView;
   AdRequest adRequest;
   private final int SHOW_ADS = 1;
   private final int HIDE_ADS = 0;

   protected Handler handler = new Handler() {
      @Override
      public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
         switch (msg.what) {
         case SHOW_ADS: {
            System.out.println("SHOW ADVIEW");
            adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            break;
         }
         case HIDE_ADS: {
            adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            break;
         }
         }
      }
   };

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      // Create the layout
      RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

      // Do the stuff that initialize() would do for you
      requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
      getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FORCE_NOT_FULLSCREEN);

      // Create the libgdx View
      View gameView = initializeForView(new MyGdxGame(this), false);

      // Create and setup the AdMob view`enter code here`
      adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, "XXXXXX"); // Put in your
                                                // secret key
                                                // here
      adRequest = new AdRequest();
      adView.loadAd(adRequest);
      // adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());

      // Add the libgdx view
      layout.addView(gameView);

      // Add the AdMob view
      RelativeLayout.LayoutParams adParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
      adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
      adParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

      layout.addView(adView, adParams);

      // Hook it all up
      setContentView(layout);
   }

   // This is the callback that posts a message for the handler
   @Override
   public void showAds(boolean show) {
      handler.sendEmptyMessage(show ? SHOW_ADS : HIDE_ADS);
   }
}
```

I read topic [Using interstitials from Admob in a Libgdx game for Android, it's slow when dismissing it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981956/using-interstitials-from-admob-in-a-libgdx-game-for-android-its-slow-when-dism)
but not solution
Please help me if you have a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue and at the moment you cant change it.

[Post at the libgdx Forum](http://badlogicgames.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=12558)

It has nothing todo with your code. I think

Comment: Thanks for your comment. My problem seem only occurs with my device :D.I've tried on the other devices, it work well :)

Comment: You're wellcome. This is still a known issue and depens on the device. Some devices drop down to 30fps while they regulary work at 60fps